# Summing count of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

What do I need to change in the SQL to sum the msr_cnt field grouped into project_ref?

```
    select      m.project_ref,
            (   select count(*)
                from (values (m.[EWI/IWI]), (m.Glazing), (m.Solar), (m.CWI), (m.Boiler), (m.TRV), (m.LI), (m.RIRI), (m.UFI), (m.ASHP)) as v(col)
                where v.col <> ''
            ) as 'msr_cnt'
from        SMSDB1.dbo.ops_measure m
where       'msr_cnt' <> '0'
--group by  m.project_ref
```

The current output is

| project_ref | msr_cnt |
| --- | --- |
| WHGSHDF | 2 |
| WHGSHDF | 2 |
| WHGSHDF | 2 |
| WHGSHDF | 2 |
| WHGSHDF | 2 |
| WHGSHDF | 2 |
| WHGSHDF | 2 |

I need it to show

| project_ref | msr_cnt |
| --- | --- |
| WHGSHDF | 14 |

I just can't quite get it over the line.

Comment: change subquery to a join?

Comment: You should avoid using the string syntax for aliases. Either don't use quotes at all or the ANSI compliant double quotes. Also, when checking that a count <> 0 you do not want to check against the string literal '0'. But for the question at hand it is impossible to answer because the query is so odd and there is no table definitions or sample data to help.

Comment: Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought this should work:

```
select
    m.project_ref,
    sum (select count(*)
         from (values (m.[EWI/IWI]), (m.Glazing), (m.Solar), (m.CWI), (m.Boiler), (m.TRV), (m.LI), (m.RIRI), (m.UFI), (m.ASHP)) as v(col)
         where v.col <> ''
    ) as msr_cnt
from SMSDB1.dbo.ops_measure m
where msr_cnt <> '0'
group by m.project_ref
```