# SQL sum the count of populated fields grouped by another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, count, sum

How do I sum the count of populated fields.

An example of the data.

[image]

The desired output would be.

[image]

This is what I have managed so far.

```
select      m.project_ref,
        (   select count(*)
            from (values (m.[EWI/IWI]), (m.Glazing), (m.Solar), (m.CWI), (m.Boiler), (m.TRV), (m.LI), (m.RIRI), (m.UFI), (m.ASHP)) as v(col)
            where v.col <> ''
        ) as 'msr_cnt'
from        SMSDB1.dbo.ops_measure m
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you tag the RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: I'm running SQLS on Azure.

Comment: There's multiple different database engines that can be run on Azure, @Ian , that doesn't really narrow it down.

Comment: BTW. note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203839/summing-count-of-multiple-columns

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text

Comment: Thanks Sean. I tried to reword and add to the comments on my previous post, but was unable/didn't know how to reformat. And If I just delete the previous question, I understand I can be marked down?  A lot of feedback to take on re formatting and stack overflow etiquette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the conditional aggregation :

```
select project_ref, sum(case when EWI_IWI <> '' then 1 else 0 end )
                    + sum(case when Glazing <> '' then 1 else 0 end ) 
                    + ... as msr_count
from mytable
group by project_ref
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from the data provide how you are calculating msr_count, but a simple GROUP BY might be the answer here:

```
SELECT
   project_ref
  ,count(*)  msr_count
 from  SMSDB1.dbo.ops_measure
 group by
   project_ref
```

Comment: Thanks Philip, but this gives me a record count. What was needed was a count of the non-blank columns grouped by project_ref column. There are 23 populated populated "cells" (sorry don't know the correct term) for WHGSHDF and 27 for WHGNRWC.